# Finding number of subgroups of order $3$ in abelian $108$ order group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that there are two finite abelian groups of order $108$ that have exactly four subgroups of order 3.

The solution says to figure out all of the isomorphism classes, then which groups have exactly $8$ elements of order $3$. I figured out that $\mathbb{Z}_{9}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$,and $\mathbb{Z}_{9}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ both have eight elements of order $3$.

My question is, doesn't having eight elements of order $3$ imply that there are two $\textbf{cyclic}$ subgroups of order $3$?

For example the next problem asked to find which finite abelian groups of order $108$ have exactly $13$ subgroups of order $3$, and I got the answer correct by determining which isomorphism classes have exactly $26$ elements of order $3$. Then dividing the number of elements by $\phi(3)=2$,to get $13$ distinct cyclic subgroups in the group but doesn't this give the number of cyclic subgroups not all subgroups?

Are there any problems of this type with finite abelian groups with different order, where I am asked to find the number of subgroups of a specific order, where this technique would not be correct for obtaining the correct isomorphism classes, with the correct number of subgroups?

Comment: Each subgroup of order 3 contains $\phi(3)=2$ elements of order 3, since all groups of order 3 are cyclic (since they are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3$)

Comment: @player3236 ok so this is only true since all of the subgroups of order three must be cyclic. Or I mean that's why I can solve the problem by determining the number of elements of order three in each group.

Comment: Yes. You can't determine the number of subgroups of order 4 of some group by looking at the number of order 4 elements, for example; you could be missing some $\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$. 3 being prime is essential.